# How to implement a .tranpose() as .T (like in numpy)

Tags: python, numpy, class, transpose

Let's say I have the following class containing a Numpy array `a`.

```py
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.a = a
        self.other_attributes = b
    def transpose(self):
        return MyClass(self.a.T,self.other_attributes)
```

Since this "transpose the data, keep the rest unchanged" method will be used quite often, I would like to implement a short-named attribute like Numpy's `.T`. My problem is that I don't know how to do it without calling `.transpose` at initialization, i. e., I only want to do the transpose when it is required, instead of saving it in another attribute. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `property` to compute attributes. This can also be used to cache computed results for later use.

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.other_attributes = b

    @property
    def T(self):
        try:
            return self._cached_T  # attempt to read cached attribute
        except AttributeError:
            self._cached_T = self._transpose()  # compute and cache
            return self._cached_T

    def _transpose(self):
        return MyClass(self.a.T, self.other_attributes)
```

Since Python 3.8, the standard library provides [`functools.cached_property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cached_property) to automatically cache computed attributes.

```
from functools import cached_property

class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.other_attributes = b

    @cached_property
    def T(self):
        return self._transpose()

    def _transpose(self):
        return MyClass(self.a.T, self.other_attributes)
```

Answer (score 0):

A transpose is just a view of the data, so "computing" the transpose at instantiation doesn't actually cost anything.

```
In [11]: a = np.random.rand(2, 1)

In [12]: a
Out[12]: 
array([[0.22316214],
      [0.69797139]])

In [13]: b = a.T

In [14]: a[0] = 1

In [15]: b
Out[15]: array([[1.        , 0.69797139]])
```